# CakePHP hasMany and hasOne

Tags: php, cakephp

Say I have the next models:

```
Order hasMany OrderLine   (OrderLine belongsTo Order)
OrderLine hasOne Product  (Product belongsTo OrderLine)
```

I want to save a new Order with many OrderLines where each OrderLine has one Product.
For example: a user want to buy a 'PS3' and a 'XBOX' so my database must be like this:

```
orders
+----+-------- +
| id | user_id |
+--------------+
| 1  | 10      |

orders_line
+------+----------+------------+
| id   | order_id | product_id |
+-----------------+------------+
| 100  |   1      |   1001     |
| 101  |   1      |   1002     |

products
+-------+------+
| id    | name | ...
+--------------+
| 1001  | PS3  |
| 1002  | BOX  |
```

I can save the Order and the OrderLines with `saveAll`

**OrdersController.php**

```
  public function add() {
     if ($this->request->isPost()) {
        $this->Order->create();
        $this->request->data['Order']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->Order->saveAll($this->request->data);
     }
  }
```

That works nice. But I don't know how to save the Products elements.

My form:

```
<form ...>
<div id="order-lines">
   <div>
      <input name="data[OrderLine][0][user_id]" type="hidden">
      <div class="span3">
         <label>myfield/label>
         <input name="data[Product][0][myfield]" type="text" id="Product0Myfield">
      </div>
      <div>
         <label>fieldb</label>
         <input name="data[Product][0][fieldb]" type="text" id="Product0Fieldb">
      </div>

   <div>
      <input name="data[OrderLine][1][id]" type="hidden">
      <div>    
         <input name="data[Product][1][id]" type="hidden">
         <label>myfield</label>
         <input name="data[Product][1][myfield]" type="text" id="Product1Myfield">
      </div>

      <div class="span3">
         <label>fieldb</label>
         <input name="data[Product][1][fieldb]" type="text" id="Product1Fieldb">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I've tried this:

```
foreach ($this->request->data['OrderLine'] as &$orderLine) {
    // create the product and populate it with form data
    $this->Product->create();
    $this->Product->save($this->request->data);
    // trying to update the OrderLine foreign key
    $orderLine['product_id'] = $this->Product->id; // doesn't works 
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: try `$orderLine['product_id'] = $this->Product->getInsertId();` and check the `Product` record is being saved/created. - but elaborate on `doesn't work` as well

Comment: And you want to create the Products along with an Order? I'd think the Products are already in the DB and you only have to set the correct IDs, but maybe you're trying to do something different here?

Comment: @lethal-guitar the Products are not in the DB. Actually I've resolved it but I think my solution is very 'ugly'. I'll post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => array(
        [Order] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 10
        )

        [OrderLine] => array(
            [0] => array
            (
                [product_id] => 1001
            )
            [1] => array
            (
                [product_id] => 1002
            )
        )
    [1] => array(...)
)
```

Which means your form should look like this:

```
data[0][Order][user_id]
data[0][OrderLine][0][product_id]
data[0][OrderLine][1][product_id]

data[1][Order][user_id]
data[1][OrderLine][0][product_id]
data[1][OrderLine][1][product_id]
```

and so on...

Save everything in one call with the option `array('deep' => true)` (see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array) or with a loop:

```
foreach ($this->request->data as $data)
    $this->Order->saveAll($data)
```

Comment: So I should change my database design? What is ProductLine?

Comment: Sorry, meant OrderLine. No, not your db design. Only how you structure your array to be saved in your db. If you are unsure, use `debug($this->request->data)` in your action to see if your data structure matches my example.

Answer (score 1):

My solution, any feedback is welcome.

I don't use `saveAll`
**OrdersController.php**

```
  public function add() {
     if ($this->request->isPost()) {
        $this->Order->create();
        $this->request->data['Order']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->Order->save($this->request->data);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($this->request->data['OrderLine'] as &$orderLine) {
           $this->OrderLine->create();
           $this->OrderLine->set('order_id', $this->Order->id);
           $this->Product->create();
           $this->Product->save($this->request->data['OrderLine'][$i]['Product'][$i]);
           $this->OrderLine->set('product_id', $this->Product->id);
           $this->OrderLine->save($this->request->data['OrderLine']);
           $i++;
        }
        $this->redirect(array(
           'controller' => 'sites',
           'action' => 'index'
        ));
     }
  }
```

And my form, well, actually I've used JavaScript to generate the form:

```
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $('#new-order-line').click(function() {
        $(
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
            '<div class="span3">' +                                                                                                   
                '<input name="data[OrderLine][' + i + '][user_id]" type="hidden"/>' +
                '<input name="data[OrderLine][' + i + '][product_id]" type="hidden"/>' +
                '<label>FieldA</label>' +
                '<input name="data[OrderLine][' + i + '][Product][' + i + '][field_a]" type="text" id="OrderLine' + i + 'ProductFielda"/>' +
            '</div>' + 
            '<div class="span3">' +
                '<label>FieldB</label>' +
                '<input name="data[OrderLine][' + i + '][Product][' + i + '][field_b]" type="text" id="OrderLine' + i + 'ProductFieldb"/>' +
            '</div>' + 
        '</div>'
        ).fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#order-lines');
        $('.oculto').removeAttr('disabled');
        ++i;
    });
});
```

My changes in the form: I've added the `data[OrderLine][i]` to the Product inputs.

Comment: I've realized that this is a nasty solution. I think that @Yoggi's solution is better.